# In CSS, how do I style a div that has two classes?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with the following CSS class defined:

```
<div class="ui-button ui-state-active">bla bla bla</div>
```

I am trying to define the CSS styling for that class by doing it this way

```
<style>
    .ui-button .ui-state-active {
        background-color:#000000;
    }
</style>
```

It's not working, am I referring to the class in the wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space:

```
.ui-button.ui-state-active
```

**with** the space, the rule says "elements with the class `ui-state-active` that are *descendants* of elements with the class `ui-button`".

Specifying multiple classes is [buggy in IE6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multipleclasses.html): To IE6, the rule will apply to all elements with the class `ui-state-active`. (Thanks @Meder for the reminder)

Comment: +1 But just to clarify, by children you mean descendants. Children´s is the > operator. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Comment: @lasse you're right, cheers. Need to start using that to avoid confusion.

Comment: What if my the class statement is this:
<div class="ui-button ui-state-active ui-other-widgets ui-more-buttons">

Do I need to include ALL classes in my css? or will the css statement above work?

Comment: @Or W no, you don't have to specify those classes together like `classname.classname.classname` . You would usually even want to specify them separately! You can also specify classes in the markup that don't exist. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

```
.ui-button.ui-state-active {}
```

Though this probably won't work in IE6, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the class to ui-state-active and copy the css over? (I know it's duplicating code)

```
<div class="ui-state-active">bla bla bla</div>

<style>
.ui-button {
    background-color:#000000;
}
.ui-state-active {
    background-color:#000000;
    color:blue;
}
</style>
```